Mitigating Single-Point Failure in an I2C Bus for Satellite ADCS
I'm working on the ADCS for a radio occultation satellite and have connected multiple peripherals to a single I2C bus. My team raised concerns about the risk of a single peripheral failure taking down the entire bus, which could render all connected devices unusable—a problem reportedly common in many missions.
I’ve been exploring the use of I2C isolators to mitigate this risk but am struggling to find isolators with flight heritage. Does anyone have recommendations for reliable approaches that could address this issue in a space-grade system?

The best we ever came up with was to have the power system monitor the i2c bus for extended low periods and then reset the whole satellite. This only catches certain types of bugs and if your  i2c hardware has shorted to ground it’s not getting fixed with a reset

First of all, part recommendations are generally off limit on this forum.  And I2C is  a bad choice for a hi-rel application like you seem to have.

You said "multiple peripherals" are on a single I2C bus.  Are these boards, boxes, something else?  If you lose the I2C bus, do you lose the whole mission?  That is, brick your payload?  Can you use some of your peripherals and still perform your mission?

Supplier recommendations are off-limits, but OP is asking about technique more than anything else: it's reasonable to assume that any components will be multiply-sourced.

You've got as many I2C buses as the number of pairs of unused GPIO pins you have got. There's not that much benefit to using the I2C bus hardware usually. There's a niche for them on relatively slow MCUs and 1MHz bus speeds, but not much else.
I2C can be easily bit-banged, especially if you have low-overhead interrupts or an I/O accelerator that could be used for that.
Prefer point-to-point connections over buses for communications between subsystems.

If you have a microcontroller where you can map the hardware I2C bus to different pairs of pins, you could dynamically remap to different pins for each target device. You just need to make sure the bus is idle before remapping. I used that approach in one project and it worked well.

@DoxyLover Great idea!
